# How do I add a js variable to the url when using the href setAttribute function?

Tags: javascript, variables, url, href, setattribute

I'm using jquery to grab a variable in the url (http://website.com?Name=Brian) and setting a javascript variable as such:

```
var name = getQueryVariable('Name');
```

Now I'm trying to dynamically update an href property in Unbounce (unbounce.com) as follows:

```
  document.getElementById('lp-pom-button-181').setAttribute("href","http://google.com?fname=name");
```

so that I can pass the variable on.

How do I add the 'var name' to the end of the url 'http://google.com?fname=' for the setAttribute href?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple string concatenation, combined with `encodeURIComponent`:

```
document.getElementById('lp-pom-button-181').setAttribute("href","http://google.com?fname=" + encodeURIComponent(name));
```

You need `encodeURIComponent` to ensure that the query string parameter is properly escaped. For instance, to ensure that `&` (which is a special character in query strings) is correctly encoded as `%26`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply T.J.  I'll be the first to admit I don't know javascript.  PHP is more my playground and I'm a novice at that.

I'm using jquery to pull the variables out of the url and I'm pretty sure the variables are already escaped.

Just to make sure, I tried adding the variable while also making sure the query string parameter was escaped per your suggestion, and no dice.  Thoughts?

Comment: I spoke with a friend who mentioned that I could use jQuery to accomplish the same thing:

`code`    $('#lp-pom-button-181').attr('href', 'http://google.com?fname=' + name); `code`

Comment: @brianjambor: **If** the text in the variable is already encoded, then obviously you don't have to encode it. But I suspect that text probably isn't. In any case, the above *does* work: http://jsbin.com/senavusu/1